# Printing oversized PDF to HP printer

Tags: printing, rhel7, cups, pdf

I am using an HP E60055 laserjet printer and using Red Hat Linux Cups version 1.6 to print to it.  Previously using a Samsung SCX-483x - with which I had no problems with the default settings.

When I print line-by-line reports the printer's default settings work well (with the correct printer driver).  But when I try to print an oversized PDF to the printer it looses most of the very top line.

If I set the **fit-to-page** property for the printer the PDF prints perfectly, but the line-by-line report gets squashed up to the top of the page.

The above doesn't completely surprise me.  But I wonder how I can print the PDF and standard reports to the same printer without changing the settings each time.
I've tried **removing the borders** (by setting them to zero) and tried using a **scaling** property but to no avail.  Can someone help me with settings that might allow both types of printout to work together?